# How does && work within a batch/cmd script?

Tags: command-line

<sup>*(I am using Win10 20H2)*</sup> 
I know if you have `command A && command B`, then `command B` only executes if `command A` was "completed successfully", but how exactly is it decided whether `command A` was successful or not?

- My first thought was that it must be based on `errorlevel`'s, but that can't be it as the following shows if you press enter without entering an input, then, as expected, you will not see a "success" message and the `errorlevel` is changed to `1`:

  ```cmd
  @echo off
  :loop
  set /p u_p= && echo success
  echo current errorlevel %errorlevel%
  goto loop
  ```

  However, if you subsequently enter valid inputs, you get a success message despite the `errorlevel` remaining at `1`, so what is triggering the `&&` to give the success message?
- It has been suggested delayed expansion might be needed, as without it the code is false reporting the current `errorlevel`, however I've tried that, along with replacing the line referencing the `errorlevel`, but I still get the outputs to indicate success despite the `errorlevel` not being `0` for all subsequent inputs after entering an empty input:

  ```cmd
  if errorlevel 1 (echo current errorlevel geq 1) else (echo current errorlevel leq 0)
  ```

I am reasonably certain the explanation is not `&&` *is* being triggered by a `0` `errorlevel`, but that the code is causing a false reporting of the `errorlevel`?

Answer (score 1):

#### My first thought was that it must be based on errorlevels.

It is, but you are missing `enabledelayedexpansion`.

This is required because there is effectively a loop in your script and without `enabledelayedexpansion` the `errorlevel` variable is set the first time through and then doesn't change.

Using `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` will give the behaviour you are expecting:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
:loop
set /p u_p= && echo success
echo current errorlevel %errorlevel%
goto loop
endlocal
```

> **EnableDelayedExpansion**
>
> Setting `EnabledDelayedExpansion` will cause each variable to be
> expanded at execution time rather than at parse time.

Source [Setlocal - Local variables - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)

Comment: That doesn't work for me, even if I replace the %s with!s?

Comment: @TechHorse <shrug> Works for me. I **have** tested it.

Comment: I am using Win 10 20H2. I do not think it sets an errorlevel for valid set/p inputs. Perhaps you're version is different.

Comment: I have added anedit to include steps I have taken to ensure that the explanation is not just the code false reporting the errorlevel.

Comment: According to the claims at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34987885/what-are-the-errorlevel-values-set-by-internal-cmd-exe-commands the errorlevel, once set to 1 by not entering an actual value, will never be reset to 0. See Table 3 re the set /p command.

Comment: @kreemoweet That table does not agree with my test program.

Answer (score 0):

> *How does `&&` work in a Batch File?*
>
> - `&&` will execute the next command when the previous command `returns 0`
> - `||` will execute the next command when the previous command `returns non 0`

*Almost all applications and utilities will set an [Exit Code](https://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html) when they complete/terminate:*

You won't get `return 0` useful with the `set /p` command, it makes no effect accurate waiting for the `&&` (`return 0`) to execute the next command, especially if it's on the ***[same line](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)***, regardless of whether `setlocal` is enabled or not

- Success is [defined](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html) as returning an `%ERRORLEVEL% = 0`; care must be taken in using this syntax to read and `SET` variables, as by default variables are expanded one line at a time
- It is not accurate to execute a command after defining a variable without checking if it has been defined or not, nor if the value is in the desired scope, layout, length, etc.

Whatever the input, whether it was given or not, it ends if **<kbd>Enter</kbd>** was pressed, in which case you have `errorlevel 0`, if **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>** was used, it would end that you have `errorlevel 1` in this way, outside of this scenario, no has a lot of use for `&&` and/or `||`.

---

- For something more precise, I suggest checking if any values ​​are assigned / assumed in your variable:

  ```bat
  if defined u_p (do) else (do instead)

  rem or ::

  if not "" == "%u_p%" (do) else (do instead)
  ```

---

- Porting to your code, I suggest something simple:

  ```bat
  @echo off

  :loop
  set "u_p="

  set /p u_p= || goto loop
  if "%u_p%" == "" goto :loop

  rem ::  do next command here ...
  ```

---

#### Additional Resources:

- [`Set /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)
- [`ErrorLevel`](https://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html)
- [Redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)

  - `|`, `<`, `>`, `2>`, etc.
- [Conditional Execution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)

  - [`||`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html) and [`&&`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)
- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter [`cmd.exe`] Parse Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699/6819406)